# Use Object's name as an object type

Tags: scripting

I am really new to coding and I have begun trying by myself, copying code and templates, reading, and so on.

I am trying to use selected objects' names in a scene to be detected as one of the predefined types in an internal addon we use in our team.

The code I wrote is the next:

```
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if ob.type != 'MESH':
        continue

    if ob.type == 'MESH':
        conName = ("'" + ob.name.upper() + "'")
        bpy.context.object.addon_submesh_type = conName
```

It seems to be working except for the last line. I know because I copied it in the console and returned all of the text values correctly.

As the predefined types of the addon are wrote in uppercase and between hyphens, like this: 'MESH' .

What I am trying to do is for example: having and object named Head, to be recognized and converted to HEAD type.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What is `bpy.ops.object.qmesh_submesh_type` ?

Comment: That's the addon's submesh type I am trying to assing based on the object's name

Comment: `name = ob.name.upper()` will suffice. It is very unlikely it is `name = "'NAME'"`  There is no need to test for type to be mesh the second time, it can't get there unless it is a mesh. And one would assume it's `ob.some_addon_prop = ob.name.upper()` not only the context object.